# Why is the code displaying blank rather than strings in C?

Tags: c, string, char, integer

I would like the code to display strings from user input, but the code is displaying blank. Sometimes, it also displays null and integers rather than strings.

Here's the code snippet:

```
typedef struct list{
    char DATA[30];
    int last;
} LIST;

LIST L;

int main(){
    char x

    printf("Enter name:");scanf(" %s",&x);insert(x);

    display();getch();
}

void insert (char x){
    L.last++;
    L.DATA[L.last] = x;
}

void display(){
system("cls");
printf("The list contains:\n");
    for (int i=0;i<=L.last;i++){
    printf("%d. %s\n",i+1,L.DATA[i]);
    }
}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&x)` hmm... `%s` is for scanning a string but `x` is ant integer. Use `%d` for scanning integers.

Comment: Make sure to use %s for displaying strings and not %d

Edit: sniped

Comment: `printf("%d.) %d\n",i+1,L[MAX].DATA[i]);` Once again: `%d` is for integers, `%s` is for strings. You probably want `printf("%d.) %s\n",i+1,L[i+1].DATA);` (or just `i` instead of `i+1`)

Comment: BTW: `%c` is for characters if that's what you want.

Comment: Also notice: `L[MAX]` is out of bounds access, i.e. outside the array.

Comment: Your question does not have a proper [mre]. It contains none of the required things: input; expected or actual output; or explanation of what the *entire* code fragment in the question is expected to do.

Comment: `L[MAX]` is always out of bounds. Your definition is: `LIST L[MAX];` which means that you may acces `L[0]`, `L[1]`, `L[2]`, ... `L[MAX-1]` But **not** `L[MAX]` - it is outside the array

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you are trying to do. You have the array `L` but you don't use it like an array. You always access `L[MAX]` which is illegal.

Comment: My suggestion: Simplify the code to only contain the `insert` and `display` part. Add a more detailed explanation of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You took the [tour] already, now please read "[ask]" if you haven't. Then come back and [edit] your question, please. Provide the [example] asked for. -- Your source is terrible to read. Please embrace some common code style and stick to it. One line for each statement, consistent indentation, whitespace, ... -- "_I didn't expect answers to be coming this fast_" Well, you have **not** got any answer. All these are just comments to help you enhancing your question. An answer will be shown as such.

Comment: Ok, I removed unnecessary code. How's that? Still getting the same results btw.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have a string type, only a character type. When you declare `char x` to hold your string, that is a single character not an entire string. I have replaced that with `char x[100]` - which declares an array of 100 characters to hold the string. If that is not long enough, you can increase it. I then changed `insert()` and `LIST` to take a `char*` (a pointer to the array of characters) instead of a single `char`.

Your list had an issue with the `insert()` function not writing to the first list element. I fixed that by writing to the list before incrementing `L.last`. I also fixed an issue with the `display` function printing a nonexisting list element by changing `<=` to `<` in your for loop.

```
typedef struct LIST
{
    char* DATA[30];
    int last;
} LIST;

LIST L;

void insert (char* x);
void display();

int main(){
    char x[100]; // Declare a character array to hold our string.
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", x); // Read the string into the array.
    insert(x); // Pass the memory address of the array to insert().
    display();
    getch();
}

void insert (char *x)
{
    L.DATA[L.last] = x; // Put the memory address of the array into the list.
    L.last++; // Increment the list counter.
}

void display()
{
    printf("The list contains:\n");
    for (int i=0; i < L.last; i++)
    { // Loop over the list, printing
        printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, L.DATA[i]);
    }
}
```

NOTE: Since the array is only 100 characters long, if a user enters more than 99 characters it will cause a buffer overflow and break the program. Also, the array is automatically deallocated if the function it is declared in exits (this is fine if its's declared in main() like it is here though). If this is an issue, you should look at using `getline()` which can automatically allocate a suitably sized string instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: I tried the code however the entries override the previous ones with the current. So I get results like:

1. Ron
2. Ron
3. Ron
4. Ron

The code should do this:

1. Ron
2. Ram
3. Joy
4. Kath

Comment: You should try using ```malloc()``` to allocate your character array instead of ```char x[100]```. This way it is not deallocated when the function exits. I think that this is your problem. You could also look at using ```getline()``` as I mentioned earlier.